# What should I do with this broken toilet flange? Is it glued in?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, level

I bought a house (foreclosed one) - and found a basement toilet was completely disconnected from the ground. So I picked it up and moved it away - and I'm gonna get a replacement toilet. But should I replace this toilet flange as well? Is it glued in you think?

[image]

[More Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0zyt.jpg)

Comment: Flange means different things to different people. Can you post a pic?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate that cast iron metal thing (blue).

Comment: Good pic... I agree with @Mazura that you probably shouldn't touch it.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it leaks, or you have access below and want to gut the plumbing, don't touch it; just add a repair ring: (use solid 1/8" steel ones to save space, not the flimsy, flanged type which are overall larger in size; even with these you may have to shim the toilet. I find that grout fills the gap between the porcelain and tile nicely, whether or not the toilet is riding high)

Metal Toilet Flange, Quick Repair Ring ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FHBGEC))

[image]

Comment: I totally agree with using a repair ring but I would never grout (or caulk) between the toilet and the floor. Future (inevitable) failure of wax ring would then become undetectable until way too late.

Comment: If you grout it, the toilet can't rock and the wax ring will never fail. If I have any doubt whatsoever, I use two.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a black, rubber flap stuck to the bottom of the seat where the bowl drains to the pluming, then that part needs to come off. There will be a new one on the new wax ring that you'll need to buy.